# SELECT DISTINCT without ordering the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, colum2 FROM table.... WHERE....
```

but I don't want that the result returned were in order.
How can I avoid that sql **sort** this rows?

Comment: There is no defined order to the data unless you use `ORDER BY`.  What sort are you referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not getting sort per se, they are just returning using whatever index is on your table or just scanning the whole table. If you want them sort randomly, then you need to explicitely say so on your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1, colum2 
      FROM table.... 
      WHERE....) A
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1da9f/19)

Comment: @njk, This does not work [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1da9f/3). To be able to order a `DISTINCT` list, `ORDER BY column` must be in the `SELECT list` but if you add newid() to the select list it won't give the expected results.

Comment: @Lamak `ORDER BY NEWID()` just sorts by random order and not according to the original rows order, OP wants to avoid that sql sort keeping the OG order

Comment: The order is variable. It doesn´t work in my case.. IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
 Id INT IDENTITY,
 Campo VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
(
    Campo
)
VALUES
('Z'),('Y'),('X')


SELECT * FROM #tmp 

SELECT A.Campo AS NuevoOrden
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CAMPO
      FROM #tmp 
      ) A
ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT DISTINCT Campo FROM #tmp 

DROP TABLE #tmp

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY isn't required for SELECT DISTINCT (or anything else)...What kind of ordering are you seeing? It may just be that the data was ordered when it was entered into the system.

Comment: Alphabetical, but I need that the data show without ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The `select distinct` has to identify duplicate rows.  There are basically two ways to do this.  One is to sort the data (which may be done implicitly using an index).  Then duplicate rows appear next to each other.  The other is to build a hash table.  Duplicate rows appear in the same hash buckets.

For your query, SQL Server is choosing to sort the data.  It happens to look like the data is being ordered.  On a multi-threaded system, then the data might *look* sorted, but when you scroll through it, you'll find that the sorting is in chunks (as data is returned from each thread).